# Parsing httpline

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, http

I have an HTTP server class (.hpp & cpp).  I am trying to improve reserve data from the socket class because I have `s.getline()` to get HTTP call.  My `s.RecvData()` gets data line by line in an infinite loop to build HTTP struct.

This is my old code:

```
while (1) {
    line = s.RecvData();
    //httpline  = s.Getline();
    if (line.empty()) break;
    //find location of tab"\t"
    int location_tab_char = line.find_first_of(" ");
    int loacation_End_chars = line.find_first_of("\r\n");
    if (loacation_End_chars == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    if ("Host:" == line.substr(0, location_tab_char))
    {
        req.hostName_ = line.substr(0, loacation_End_chars);
    }
    else if ("Connection:" == line.substr(0, location_tab_char))
    {
        req.conn_ = line.substr(0, loacation_End_chars);
    }
    else    if ("Accept:" == line.substr(0, location_tab_char))
    {
        req.accept_ = line.substr(0, loacation_End_chars);
    }
    else if ("Accept-Language:" == line.substr(0, location_tab_char))
    {
        req.acceptLanguage_ = line.substr(0, loacation_End_chars);
    }
    else if ("Accept-Encoding:" == line.substr(0, location_tab_char))
    {
        req.acceptEncoding_ = line.substr(0, loacation_End_chars);
    }
    else if ("User-Agent:" == line.substr(0, location_tab_char))
    {
        req.userAgent_ = line.substr(0, loacation_End_chars);
    }
}
```

I just need a way to improve it because getting data from the socket line by line is too much calling.  Also, when I pass to struct, I pass this string "Host: 169.254.80.80:8080"

> "Host: 169.254.80.80:8080\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\nUser-Agent:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6 ";

Comment: You should go for [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to parse the header. You can check out other HTTP server's source code to see how they implement that. (with regex, I guess).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code can be made smaller and without repeated constructs, by mapping your keys to values in a map:

```
// #include <map>

std::map<std::string,std::string> headers;

while(true) { // better use true instead of 1

    line = s.RecvData();

    if (line.empty() || line == "\r\n\r\n")
        break;
    auto key_value_sep = line.find(":"); // do not split by space

    // you could stop here in case of an exception in the data
    // if(0 == key_value_sep || std::string::npos == key_value_sep)
    //     throw std::runtime_error{"..."}; // or break, or whatever

    // line is a single line; as such, end chars location not needed
    // int loacation_End_chars = line.find_first_of("\r\n");

    auto key = line.substr(0, key_value_separator);

    auto value = line.substr(key_value_separator + 2, // skip ": "
                             line.size() - key.size() - 4); // size less key,
                                                            // separator and
                                                            // "\r\n"
    // you could break here in case of an exception in the data
    // if (value.empty() || key.empty()) || ...)
    //     throw std::runtime_error{"..."}; // or break, or whatever

    // set header 
    headers[key] += value;
}

// set headers (or use directly from map)
req.hostName_ = headers["Host"];
req.conn_ = headers["Connection"];
req.accept_ = headers["Accept"];
req.acceptLanguage_ = headers["Accept-Language"];
req.acceptEncoding_ = headers["Accept-Encoding"];
req.userAgent_ = headers["User-Agent"];
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a few notes about style:

- You probably have a typo in `loacation_End_chars`. I think that you meant `location_End_chars` instead.
- Also, you should be consistent with `location_tab_char` and use [`snake_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) everywhere without any capital. Therefore, `loacation_End_chars` should actually be named `location_end_chars`.

---

Your program may compute `line.substr(0, location_tab_char)` an awful lot of time if it has to `"User-Agent:"`, which may be extremely inefficient. It is bad generally bad to repeat code when it could be avoided. Here, a solution would be to compute `line.substr(0, location_tab_char)` and `line.substr(0, location_end_char)` only once before your conditions:

```
std::string first = line.substr(0, location_tab_char);
std::string second = line.substr(0, location_end_chars);
if ("Host:" == first)
{
    req.hostName_ = second;
}
else if ("Connection:" == first)
{
    req.conn_ = second;
}
// etc...
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what would be good names for these variables, so I named them `first` and `second`, but you should find a relevant and meaninful name for them instead.

---

Another way to simplify your code would be to map directly the strings to the fields of your struct thanks to a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper):

```
std::map<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<std::string>> mapping = {
    { "Host:", req.hostName_ },
    { "Connection:", req.conn_ },
    { "Accept:", req.accept_ },
    { "Accept-Language:", req.acceptLanguage_ },
    { "Accept-Encoding:", req.acceptEncoding_ },
    { "User-Agent:", req.userAgent_ },    
};
```

Then your code would become:

```
while (true) {
    line = s.RecvData();
    //httpline  = s.Getline();
    if (line.empty()) break;
    //find location of tab"\t"
    int location_tab_char = line.find_first_of(" ");
    int location_end_chars = line.find_first_of("\r\n");
    if (location_end_chars == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    auto key = line.substr(0, location_tab_char);
    auto value = line.substr(0, location_end_chars);
    auto it = mapping.find(key);
    if (it != mapping.end())
    {
        it->second.get() = value;
    }
}
```

Some additional notes (thanks to @utnapistim comment):

- `std::map::operator[]` invokes the default constructor of the value type. However, `std::reference_wrapper` does not have a default constructor, that's why I used the method `at` instead (contrary to `operator[]`, `at` cannot create an element, that's why we need to check for the existence of the element beforehand with `find`).
- Of course, you `header` instance needs to live in a greater scope than the `std::map` instance, otherwise, trying to access the elements of `mapping` will trigger undefined behavior.

Comment: A note about the std::reference_wrapper use: make sure the header you are mapping has a bigger scope than the map (otherwise you end up with UB). Also, the use of std::reference_wrapper in a map imposes that you always check for existence of the value before assignment (as you did - which is non-obvious unless you know the behavior of std::map::operator[]).

Comment: @utnapistim Yeah, `std::map::operator[]` always crashes with `std::reference_wrapper` since it does not have a default constructor. I will add a note about that, thanks :)